# convent and find The difference between date time flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to help with my fluter code,
I have an API its response me a date as a String

```
 {"time": "12/04/2020 16:09:33"}
```

and I get the current time in my code from the phone using

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
```

how I can calculate the difference between two date-time???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) library.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
  return duration.toString().split('.').first.padLeft(8, '0');
}

final s = "12/04/2020 16:09:33";
final formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
final dateTime = formatter.parse(s);
var now =  DateTime.now();
var difference = now.difference(dateTime);
print(formatDuration(difference));
```

print result ex. 53:37:11

Comment: I get the 17544842 as a result... what that means? and can I get the result as a "HH:mm:ss" format ???

Comment: I got "53:37:11.601999". That mean "HH:mm:ss.microseconds". I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using `difference()` method which accepts `date` as `DateTime` object. Hence, first you need to convert your input date which is in `String` format, into `DateTime`. Working code below:

```
    String date = "12/04/2020 16:09:33";

    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    DateTime dateTime = dateFormat.parse(date); // converts into Datetime

    var nowDate = DateTime.now();

    var difference = nowDate.difference(dateTime); 
    print(difference); // 17553602:53:49.047936
```

Comment: I get the 17544842 as a result... what that means? and can I get the result as a "HH:mm:ss" format ???

Comment: I think the problem is when I convert the data because I enter the "12/04/2020 16:09:33" and the result after the converts is = "dateTime= 0017-10-11 16:09:33.000"